# Issue generating an Event Receiver Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, event-receivers

I'm new in Sharepoint and I'm generating an Event Receiver. I've created a new sharepoint blak project, added an event receiver, created the hierarchy(12/TEMPLATE/Features/MyEvent/elements.xml and feature.xml. But when I add this solution to the sharepoint and deploy is always installed as Untitled 1. If I open the wsp file generated it has a Untitled 1 folder. Can anyone help me? What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your feature.xml with Title and Description.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
         Id="*your feature id*"
         Title="*Your title here*"
         Description="*Your description here*"
         Scope="Web"
         Hidden="false"
         ReceiverAssembly=""
         ReceiverClass="">
</Feature>`

Are you using WSP.ddf? Then set the DiskDirectory1 and CabinetNameTemplate

.Set DiskDirectory1="C:\Projects\xxxx"
.Set CabinetNameTemplate="xxxx.wsp"